# primefaces dataTable with dynamic columns and filtering does no more update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a primefaces data table with dynamic columns and filtering for each column which shows search results. The data table is updated after each search execution with `update="@form"`.
Unfortunately the data table is no more updated after the user has done a filtering for a column. The data table does not show new search results after an executed search until the user changes the view and returns to the data table (the search results are stored in the session), this builds the data table new from scratch.

This is the data table xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="searchResultTableId" scrollable="true" value="#{curSearch.getSearchResults()}" scrollHeight="300" var="curSearchResult"
    sortMode="multiple" rowKey="#{curSearchResult.hashCode()}" draggableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true" styleClass="hitlistDataTable"
    paginator="true" rows="#{curSearch.hitlistRowsPerPage}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="#{curSearch.rowsPerPageTemplate}" paginatorPosition="bottom" tableStyleClass="searchResultTable"
    selection="#{curSearch.selectedSearchResults}" widgetVar="hitlistTableVar">

    <p:ajax event="colReorder" update="searchResultTableId :editPropertyFormId:editPropertyDialogId" oncomplete="hitlistTableResized();" />

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
        update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
        update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId"
        oncomplete="PF('searchResultTableContextMenuVar').show(currentEvent);" />

    <!-- double click listener -->
    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
        listener="#{editPropertyBL.initForEdit(curSearch.selectedSearchResults.get(0), curSearch.getDataViewDefinition())}"
        oncomplete="PF('editPropertyDialogVar').show();" update=":editPropertyFormId @(.resultlistActionGrid)" />

    <p:column style="width: 16px;">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width: 16px; text-align:center; padding-right: 12px;" />

    <p:columns value="#{curSearch.determinePrimaryPropertyNames()}" var="curPrimaryPropName"
        sortBy="#{curSearchResult[curPrimaryPropName].getValue()}" filterBy="#{curSearchResult[curPrimaryPropName].getValue()}"
        filterMatchMode="contains">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{displayNameResolver.resolveDisplayNameOfHitlistProperty(curPrimaryPropName, curSearch)}" />
        </f:facet>

        <ui:param name="curValue" value="#{hitlistBL.generatePropertyValue(curSearchResult, curPrimaryPropName)}" />
        <ui:param name="isDocumentTitle" value="#{hitlistBL.isDocumentTitle(curPrimaryPropName)}" />
        <ui:param name="isChoice" value="#{hitlistBL.isChoice(curPrimaryPropName, curSearch)}" />

        <!-- doc title -->
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{curSearchResult.isChanged() and (isDocumentTitle)}" style="padding-right: 4px;">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <!-- <p:commandLink action="#{contentBL.showContentExtern(curSearch.getViewId(), curSearchResult)}" value="#{curValue}" ajax="false"
            rendered="#{(curSearchResult.isOfDataType('STRING', curPrimaryPropName)) and (isDocumentTitle) and (not isChoice)}" target="_blank" /> -->

        <!-- document title -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" title="#{curSearchResult.getRepresentationsAsString()}"
            rendered="#{(curSearchResult.isOfDataType('STRING', curPrimaryPropName)) and (isDocumentTitle) and (not isChoice)}" />

        <!-- data type STRING -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}"
            rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('STRING', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isDocumentTitle) and (not isChoice)}" />

        <!-- data type UUID -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('UUID', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}" />

        <!-- data type INTEGER32 -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('INTEGER32', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
            <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" groupingUsed="false" />
        </h:outputText>

        <!-- data type DOUBLE -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('DOUBLE', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
            <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" />
        </h:outputText>

        <!-- data type DATETIME -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('DATETIME', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" timeZone="#{settingsBL.getTimeZoneIdSet()}"
                pattern="#{settingsBL.dateTimePattern}" />
        </h:outputText>

        <!-- CHOICE -->
        <h:outputText value="#{hitlistBL.determineChoiceUiValue(curSearch.getViewId(), curSearchResult, curPrimaryPropName)}"
            rendered="#{(not isDocumentTitle) and (isChoice)}" />

    </p:columns>

    <p:rowExpansion>
        <h:panelGrid id="addPropsOuterGridId" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" columns="2" columnClasses="expRowImage, expRowProps"
            styleClass="resultListRowExpansionGrid">
            <h:panelGroup style="height: 200px;">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{imageCacheBean.image}" height="200" cache="false"
                    rendered="#{curSearchResult.isContentRepresentationWithNameExisting('thumbnails')}">
                    <f:param name="searchTabId" value="#{curSearch.getTabId().toString()}" />
                    <f:param name="searchViewId" value="#{searchViewBL.getSelectedSearchViewId().toString()}" />
                    <f:param name="searchPid" value="#{curSearchResult.getPid().getPidString()}" />
                </p:graphicImage>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:dataGrid id="addPropDataGridId" var="curSecondaryPropName" value="#{curSearch.determineSecondaryPropertyNames()}" columns="1"
                layout="grid" styleClass="hitlistAdditionalPropDataGrid" emptyMessage="">

                <ui:param name="isChoice" value="#{hitlistBL.isChoice(curSecondaryPropName, curSearch)}" />

                <h:panelGrid id="addPropsInnerGridId" columns="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    columnClasses="hitlistAddPropLabel, hitlistAddPropValue" style="width: 100%;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{displayNameResolver.resolveDisplayNameOfHitlistProperty(curSecondaryPropName, curSearch)}: " />

                    <ui:param name="curSecondaryValue" value="#{hitlistBL.generatePropertyValue(curSearchResult, curSecondaryPropName)}" />

                    <!-- data type STRING -->
                    <h:outputText value="#{curSecondaryValue}"
                        rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('STRING', curSecondaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}" />

                    <!-- data type UUID -->
                    <h:outputText value="#{curSecondaryValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('UUID', curSecondaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}" />

                    <!-- data type INTEGER32 -->
                    <h:outputText value="#{curSecondaryValue}"
                        rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('INTEGER32', curSecondaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
                        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" groupingUsed="false" />
                    </h:outputText>

                    <!-- data type DOUBLE -->
                    <h:outputText value="#{curSecondaryValue}"
                        rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('DOUBLE', curSecondaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
                        <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" />
                    </h:outputText>

                    <!-- data type DATETIME -->
                    <h:outputText value="#{curSecondaryValue}"
                        rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('DATETIME', curSecondaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
                        <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" timeZone="#{settingsBL.getTimeZoneIdSet()}"
                            pattern="#{settingsBL.dateTimePattern}" />
                    </h:outputText>

                    <!-- CHOICE -->
                    <h:outputText value="#{hitlistBL.determineChoiceUiValue(curSearch.getViewId(), curSearchResult, curSecondaryPropName)}"
                        rendered="#{isChoice}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dataGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:rowExpansion>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Did you have any errors in the console or in the page source code ?

Comment: No javascript errors and no exceptions on server side.

Comment: Where is your update="@form" in the code? Do you handle filter event in your dataTable? Did you surround you're datatable with h:form tag? Did you specify filteredValue attribute in your dataTable?

Comment: please make an mcve...

Comment: The update is done with the search button: `<p:commandButton id="doSearchButtonShortMaskId" value="#{msgs['label.button.searchTemplate.search']}" icon="searchButtonIcon"
     styleClass="searchShortButton" action="#{searchMaskBL.doSearch(curSearch)}" update="@form" process="@form"
     oncomplete="resizeResultViews();" />`

Comment: Of course the data table is inside a form (which is omnifaces form, but also with a `h:form` the update is no more done after filtering. I am using PF 5.2.6 and JSF 2.2.12 and omnifaces 2.1.

Comment: I added `filteredValue` attribute to the data table but this does not change the behaviour.

Comment: A tabView on the page is after filter no more updated also. There I get an error: `Request return with error:parsererror. primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=5.2.6:1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the filtering while doing search on button.
Use 
 `widgetVar="hitlistTableVar"` for your datatable and then

on your command button clear the filter.

```
 oncomplete="hitlistTableVar.clearFilters();"
```

Hope it should solve your problem.

`

Comment: After clearing the filter the data table is updated...thanks. The tabView problem I have mentioned is another problem how it seems.

Comment: Investigated an error the last 2 days which came with this clearFilters() call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332710/primefaces-data-for-data-table-is-getting-confused

Comment: Calling Javascript table functions after AJAX-Update will trigger a second AJAX-Request, which can lead to problems. Therefore I suggest clearing your filters in your first request on server side. Bind them with EL-Expressions if not already.