# Primefaces data for data table is getting confused

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Sorry for the title but I have to explain what I want to do and what isn't working. My web ui with JSF 2.2.10 and primefaces 5.2.6 shows a search mask and search results upon a model.
Each search instance is shown as a tab in a `tabView`. When a tab is clicked, its corresponding search instance is shown under the `tabView` in a `dataTable`. A search instance is created upon a search template, so different search instances can have different input fields and different result fields (which are the columns in the data table).
The user is able to execute the search for an existing search instance again with or without changed search fields. Here is my problem...he ui work until the user has executed a search instance 2nd time. Now when the tab in the `tabView` is changed an exception is thrown and the javascript console shows 'Request return with  error:parsererror  primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces$v=5.2.6:1'
Now the data of for instance search instance 1 is mixed up with search instance 2. A result field (data table column) from search instance 1 is tried to get from search instance 2, but this can fail.
This only occurs if a search instance is executed the 2nd time. Without 2nd execution I can change between the tabs without problem. My data structure is ok I think.
A class `SearchInstance` is "behind" a tab and contains a list of `SearchResult`. This `SearchResult` is a `Map` with the result fields.

This is the xhtml of the `tabView`. The `tabView` is only used as trigger here. A tab does not really contain the `dataTable` with the components, it updates only the form and the content is included under the `tabView`:

```
<h:form id="searchInstancesFormId">
    <p:tabView id="searchTabViewId" value="#{searchBL.searchInstances}" var="curSearch" activeIndex="#{searchBL.activeTabIndex}">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" oncomplete="resizeResultViews();" listener="#{searchBL.setSelectedSearch(curSearch)}"
            update="@form" immediate="true" process="@this" />
        <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{searchBL.removeSearchInstance(curSearch)}" update="@this"
            oncomplete="resizeResultViews();" immediate="true" process="@this" />
        <p:tab closable="#{curSearch.isCloseable()}">
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>

    <h:panelGrid id="mainSearchAreaGridId">
        <ui:include
            src="#{not searchBL.selectedSearch.closeable ? '/sections/search/firstSearchTab.xhtml' : '/sections/search/searchInstanceTab.xhtml'}">
            <ui:param name="curSearchInst" value="#{searchBL.selectedSearch}" />
        </ui:include>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

The 1st tab is the search template tab from the 2nd tab on there are search instances.

Here is the `dataTable` xhtml. The problem occurs when `curValue` is retrieved. Here in 'hitlistBL' bean the result field map is queried with the current property name. Here the name from the search instance selected before and it is tried to get the value from the new selected search instance:

```
<p:dataTable id="searchResultTableId" scrollable="true" value="#{curSearch.getSearchResults()}" scrollHeight="300" var="curSearchResult"
    sortMode="multiple" rowKey="#{curSearchResult.hashCode()}" draggableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true" styleClass="hitlistDataTable"
    paginator="true" rows="#{curSearch.hitlistRowsPerPage}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" filteredValue="#{curSearch.filteredValues}" 
    selection="#{curSearch.selectedSearchResults}" widgetVar="hitlistTableVar">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
        update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
        update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId" />
    <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update="@(.resultlistActionGrid) :searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId:searchResultTableContextMenuId"
        oncomplete="PF('searchResultTableContextMenuVar').show(currentEvent);" />

    <!-- double click listener -->
    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
        listener="#{editPropertyBL.initForEdit(curSearch.selectedSearchResults.get(0), curSearch.getDataViewDefinition())}"
        oncomplete="PF('editPropertyDialogVar').show();" update=":editPropertyFormId @(.resultlistActionGrid)" />

    <p:column style="width: 16px;">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width: 16px; text-align:center; padding-right: 12px;" />

    <p:columns value="#{curSearch.determinePrimaryPropertyNames()}" var="curPrimaryPropName"
        sortBy="#{curSearchResult[curPrimaryPropName].getValue()}" filterBy="#{curSearchResult[curPrimaryPropName].getValue()}"
        filterMatchMode="contains">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{displayNameResolver.resolveDisplayNameOfHitlistProperty(curPrimaryPropName, curSearch)}" />
        </f:facet>

        <ui:param name="curValue" value="#{hitlistBL.generatePropertyValue(curSearchResult, curPrimaryPropName)}" />
        <ui:param name="isDocumentTitle" value="#{hitlistBL.isDocumentTitle(curPrimaryPropName)}" />
        <ui:param name="isChoice" value="#{hitlistBL.isChoice(curPrimaryPropName, curSearch)}" />

        <!-- doc title -->
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{curSearchResult.isChanged() and (isDocumentTitle)}" style="padding-right: 4px;">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <!-- <p:commandLink action="#{contentBL.showContentExtern(curSearch.getViewId(), curSearchResult)}" value="#{curValue}" ajax="false"
            rendered="#{(curSearchResult.isOfDataType('STRING', curPrimaryPropName)) and (isDocumentTitle) and (not isChoice)}" target="_blank" /> -->

        <!-- document title -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" title="#{curSearchResult.getRepresentationsAsString()}"
            rendered="#{(curSearchResult.isOfDataType('STRING', curPrimaryPropName)) and (isDocumentTitle) and (not isChoice)}" />

        <!-- data type STRING -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}"
            rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('STRING', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isDocumentTitle) and (not isChoice)}" />

        <!-- data type UUID -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('UUID', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}" />

        <!-- data type INTEGER32 -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('INTEGER32', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
            <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" groupingUsed="false" />
        </h:outputText>

        <!-- data type DOUBLE -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('DOUBLE', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
            <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" />
        </h:outputText>

        <!-- data type DATETIME -->
        <h:outputText value="#{curValue}" rendered="#{curSearchResult.isOfDataType('DATETIME', curPrimaryPropName) and (not isChoice)}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" timeZone="#{settingsBL.getTimeZoneIdSet()}"
                pattern="#{settingsBL.dateTimePattern}" />
        </h:outputText>

        <!-- CHOICE -->
        <h:outputText value="#{hitlistBL.determineChoiceUiValue(curSearch.getViewId(), curSearchResult, curPrimaryPropName)}"
            rendered="#{(not isDocumentTitle) and (isChoice)}" />

    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

A search instance if executed with the following. A new search is done and the search instance member search result is exchanged with the new results:

```
<p:commandButton id="doSearchButtonFullMaskId" value="#{msgs['label.button.searchTemplate.search']}" icon="searchButtonIcon"
                styleClass="searchButton" action="#{searchMaskBL.doSearch(curSearchInst)}" update="@form" process="@form"
                oncomplete="resizeResultViews(); PF('hitlistTableVar').clearFilters();" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
```

Sorry this is a lot of text and it is quite difficult to explain. I don't know if this is my flaw or there is a bug somewhere. Maybe this javascript parsererror could give a hint, but I do not know how to get into/debug it.

Update: looks like a not wellformed xml of the ajax response?:

```
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: nicht wohlgeformt Adresse: moz-nullprincipal:  {96f3db57-4075-4d80-a250-03491a2ce33f} Zeile Nr. 90, Spalte 132: ...rrorpages/500.xhtml?dswid=-9189"></redirect>]]>]]></update></partial-response......-------------------------------------------------^
```

It points to the closing brackets of `></redirect>]]>]]><`

Comment: that means you are updating same instance of your result-set its not new instance thats why its updating new result in old tab.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. I am updating only the search result in the search instance, because the other data must not be updated.

Comment: I have no clue how the ajax update response xml is getting not wellformed. But probably the xml thing is a subsequent error?

Comment: This problem came with the call `oncomplete="hitlistTableVar.clearFilters();"`

Comment: what exactly is the error??Have you solved your problem yet

Comment: Adding `oncomplete="hitlistTableVar.clearFilters();"` to the search button lead to the problem described here (as I have already written). So the clearing solved the problem that the data table was no more updated after filtering, but lead to this problem which is a bigger problem than the filtering. So....no my problem is not solved.

Comment: its seems your ajax response is coming as null

Comment: The ajax update xml is not null but not wellformed. Probably this comes with my data table configuration like `p:columns` etc. and the column filtering. There is something not working together I think.

Comment: The only possibilty I see at this time is to deactivate the filtering to get a working data table. It seems like that the data table cannot handle the changed data model (it is changed by clicking on the tabs in the tabView (see posted code)) and simultaneously filtering. If I do any operation on filtering like `clearFiltering()` with JS or change the `filteredValues` from the backing bean it crashes.

Comment: I used this kind of combination but never faced the problem. check the DataStructure of your bean and its hard to detect the problem

Comment: Do you  have `p:columns` and do you exchange the data model of the table via ajax?

Comment: By the way...I added `oncomplete="PF('hitlistTableVar').clearFilters();"`

Comment: I don't know why this happens but it comes with the filtering. I removed all filtering  from the data table and it works.